# I tried to make caesar cipher with delimiter input in java

Tags: java, delimiter, caesar-cipher

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String message, encryptedMessage = "";
    int key;
    char ch;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    key = sc.nextInt();
    
    message = sc.nextLine();
    sc.useDelimiter(" ");
    
    // I think the problem is in the encrypting formula.

    for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); ++i){
        ch = message.charAt(i);
        
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            ch = (char)(ch + key);
            
            if(ch > 'z'){
                ch = (char)(ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
            }
            
            encryptedMessage += ch;
        }
        else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
            ch = (char)(ch + key);
            
            if(ch > 'Z'){
                ch = (char)(ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);
            }
            
            encryptedMessage += ch;
        }
        else {
            encryptedMessage += ch;
        }
    }
    
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(sc.next()+encryptedMessage);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

This is my code and I use delimiter for the text. The input I use doesn't get encrypted. I don't understand what the problem is. Can somebody help me with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the way you are accepting the [encryption] key and the message to encrypt. Using the code in your question, you need to enter an integer immediately followed by the message, for example.

```
1Abc xyz.
```

In the above example, the key is 1 (one) and the message is `Abc xyz.` You hit the <ENTER> key after entering the the last letter in the message and your code correctly generates the encrypted message which, according to my example above, is

```
Bcd yza.
```

If you hit <ENTER> after entering the [encryption] key (which is 1 in my example, above) then the "message" is an empty string. That's why it appears that your message is not encrypted.

If you step through your code with a debugger, then you would discover that "message" is an empty string. All good IDEs have a debugger. You should learn to use it.

Perhaps [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) will help you understand how `Scanner` class works.

By the way, you should not close a `Scanner` that wraps `System.in`. You can safely ignore any warnings your IDE may display about not closing the `Scanner`. Also, your last `while` loop is not required. Simply print `encryptedMessage`, i.e.

```java
System.out.println(encryptedMessage);
```

Comment: and how to make the output from A C to A <enter> C